# Django Rest Framework Permission class OR Django Middleware - Which is the best option to perform validations?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

In my REST application (built in Django REST framework) containing hundreds of APIs, few of those APIs will need to have access token validated before starting its business logic, few of those APIs will need to have a key validated before its business logic.  Likewise, there are different levels of validations to be performed on different group of APIs.

I came to know that both permission classes and middleware can be used for validation purposes.  I would like to know which of these two will be best choice for my requirement.  Any related suggestion will help us to choose the effective option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When django serve a request/view then it sequentially execute each Middleware classes and this is for every and each request response-cycle/view. So if you need same type of validation for every view then it is better to go with middleware classes.
And if you think you need customization like For different view, different type of permission class should execute then go with permission classes.

So in short 
Generalization -> Middleware.
Specification -> Permission Classes